# Absolutely positioned elements not visible in ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Can anyone tell me why the absolutely positioned navigation buttons in the top right corner of [this page](http://testing.xenongroupadmin.com/enrolment) are not visible in ie7, but are working fine in all other browsers (including ie8 and 9)

Thanks!

Comment: As a suggestion, it's usually better to paste the code you are talking about into your question - more people are likely to answer it that way plus you wont get complained at ;) *(links are very useful too though)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one you are using `display:inline-block` which isn't properly supported by IE7 or below *(sometimes it works, others not -- depends on the element and the situation)*.

Use `display:block` and `float:left` instead as this is more supported *(however if you see my first link you can using `display:inline` too)*.

Don't forget to include `overflow:hidden` in the surrounding UL element either otherwise you'll get strange results due to the float.

css:

```
#navlist {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#navlist li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  /* your styles from before */
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  color: black;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
}
```

markup:

```
<ul id="navlist">
  <li id="li1">
    <a id="link1" href="#">1</a>
  </li>
  <li id="li2">
    <a id="link2" href="#">2</a>
  </li>
  <li id="li3">
    <a id="link3" href="#">3</a>
  </li>
  <li id="li4">
    <a id="link4" href="#">4</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

useful links:

1. http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block/
2. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t03

#### update:

Another thing you could try *(if the above doesn't solve the problem)* is to temporarily remove your conditional commented code for IE7 - just to make certain there isn't anything in there causing a problem:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie7.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/ie7.js"></script> 
<![endif]-->
```

#### update:

Now that I've been able to actually test in IE7 the problem shows up if you enable borders - using css borders to debug is always a good idea :) The problem above is being caused by an child element pushing out the width of your parent element `innerWrap`. This wont affect more modern browsers, but IE7 and older always try and wrap their children no matter where they are placed or what size they are *(unless you override this behaviour)*. Because your child element `slideWrap` is 3000px wide, it is causing your right positioned elements to vanish off the edge of the screen.

The following css should fix it:

```
#innerWrap { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Hi pebbl, thanks for that. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have worked. One thing I have noticed, though, is that the nav buttons appear when you get to the final slide of the slider, as if they were contained within the slider div itself. Could this shed any light on the problem?

Comment: @Chris - yep, now that I'm home I've got access to IE7 so can test.. your problem is being caused by an element called slideWrap - it has a width of 3000 which - because elements rendered in older IEs always try and contain their children - is pushing the dimensions of innerWrap. This means position `right:0px` for IE7 is about 3000 pixels off the right of the screen. Your best way around this is to give innerWrap a specified width.

Answer (score 0):

Use left or right properties with it in order to make them visible.